# Responsive navbar only works on my home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to build my first fully responsive website and everything is working like it should except this navbar. The navbar is supposed to have a "burger" button that you press and then links pop up. The problem is that the links only pop up on my home page and not on any of my other pages.

I've tried copying the HTML code for the navbar to the other pages from the home page and all pages use the same CSS code. I think the problem must be in the Javascript but I don't have enough experience with Java to be able to figure out the problem on my own.

I haven't really found anyone with a similar problem so I'm asking this myself.

Here is the code for the navbar:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
 <div class="logo">
  <a href="https://www.pwrgear.net"><img src="assets/images/pg-logo-white-250p.png" alt="White    PWRGear Logo" title="Home"</a>
 </div>
 <ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="assets/html/order.html">Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="assets/html/reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
  <li><a href="assets/html/community.html">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="assets/html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="assets/html/about.html">About</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
 </div>
</nav>

<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Navigation Bar Start */
nav
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.nav-links
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.nav-links a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.nav-links a:hover
{
  color: red;
}

.nav-links li
{
  list-style: none;
}

.burger
{
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div
{
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
  .nav-links
  {
    margin-right: 9%;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    margin-top: 10%;
  }

  .imagetext
  {
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .header2
  {
    margin-top: 1%;
  }

  .subheader
  {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    font-size: 28px;
  }

  .subcontent
  {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
  body
  {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links
  {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .logo
  {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }

  .nav-links li
  {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .burger
  {
    display: block;
  }

  .imagetext
  {
    margin-top: -6%;
    display: none;
  }

  .subheader
  {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }

  .subcontent
  {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    margin-top: 0%;
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    display: none;
  }

  .imageheader
  {

  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:812px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:736px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    /* display: none; */
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    /* display: none; */
    margin-top: 17%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:667px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    height: 0%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    height: 5%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:414px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    margin-top: -51%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .imageheader
  {
    margin-top: -25%;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1366px)
{
  .imagetext
  {
    margin-top: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 2%;
  }

  .subheader
  {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }

  .content1
  {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
  }

  .content2
  {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
  }

  .content3
  {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px)
{
  .contactimage
  {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px)
{
  .subcontent
  {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
}

.nav-active
{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.imagetextremove
{
  display: none;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade
{
  from
  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }

  to
  {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 4px);
}

.toggle .line2
{
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3
{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -6px);
}
/* Navigation Bar End */
```

**JS**

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  const imageHeader = document.querySelector('.imageheader');
  const imageText = document.querySelector('.imagetext');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Toggle Image Text
    imageHeader.classList.toggle('imagetextremove');
    imageText.classList.toggle('imagetextremove');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
          link.style.animation = ``;
        } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.4}s`
        }

    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
  });

}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it seemed to be the imageHeader and imageText toggles. Since I didn't have those classes on all my pages the script wouldn't run. So I removed this part of the script and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the script.js in your other html pages?

Comment: Yes, I included it in all of the pages with the correct links/addresses.